# Microphone not working in Google Hangouts

Tags: microphone, google-hangouts

I am experiencing the problem described here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/n1cpJq1mC8U.

Google Hangouts appears to be resetting the levels of my microphone.

That post has a solution:

```
To turn off the auto adjust:

cd ~/.config/google-googletalkplugin    # get to google chat's directory
cp -p options options.bak        # make a backup before changing stuff ! 
gedit options                # edit the config file

now change one of the lines so that it reads as follows:

audio-flags=1
```

So far, so good. The problem is that I don't have a folder `~/.config/google-googletalkplugin`.

My Hangouts works perfectly apart from the mic, so I guess I don't need to install anything, but how do I configure it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microphone doesn't work in Hangouts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872976/microphone-doesnt-work-in-hangouts)

Answer (score 0):

I see from your question you are using a linux OS.

I had the same issue and installing [Google hangouts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) extension worked like a charm for me.

In my case, I was using chromium on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Hello, could you specify the OS you used?