# Microphone doesn't work in Hangouts

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, google-hangouts

I have a DELL inspiron 5537 i5 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. When I use Google Hangouts on Google Chrome, my mic just doesn't work. When I open the secure info setting it shows that the mic is allowed. 
Works in Windows.

I have tried to add the Hangouts plugin and it also doesn't work.

Is there any to solve the problem?

Comment: Make sure the input device is correctly selected before anything else (click the sound-indicator > sound settings).

Comment: Of course make sure [is not muted or very low](https://imgur.com/qf2LhLM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've installed [Hangout extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)

I don't know what was the problem and how that fixed it but it worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must choose your mic in hangout settings, not default but definitely your mic wich you use.